# Specific word stops entry from saving

Tags: entries, saving

I've just migrated a craft site to a staging server from a local environment and have come across an odd bug I have no idea what's causing it.

If I use the word "select" in a blog post, the entry doesn't save and instead goes to a 404 page. If I capitalise a letter, "Select" for instance, it saves fine.

It's a rich text field that has the content and this didn't happen on my local environment either. There doesn't seem to be any errors showing up in craft logs as far as I can tell either.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a `mod_security` issue.

You'll need to reach out to whoever manages your server and ask them to relax the security around saving data to all URLs under your `/admin` URL area.

What is happening behind the scenes is that the security on your server thinks that you may be trying to query the database and do something malicious. i.e. `SELECT * FROM craft_users;`